# Spring Rest duplication check some time skipping while running service with 100 users same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-safety

In my spring rest application I have created a method for registering new users. Inside that there is  email duplication check to confirm that email already registered. If so it returns error message other wise the new user will register.

While I trying to test the code with jmeter with 100 users,  some time the duplication check is skipping. And inserting 2 user with same email id.  I am creating email ids by using current system milliseconds.
Somebody please help why would this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical situation with threads. You have to synchronize them somehow. There are many options to solve it:

- use something less than milliseconds (microseconds, nanoseconds) to reduce the chance of getting the same value
- add another value to make it more random (thread id, for example)
- use `AtomicLong` and its [`incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet--) method instead of (or additional to) milliseconds
- mark the field in the database as unique (always a good idea), so it won't allow to insert duplicate values and will throw an exception. In the controller you can catch such exception and try to generate email and save it again
- mark the method that is getting the current milliseconds as `synchronized` (so it won't be possible to invoke it at the same time from the different threads, the second thread will wait for the first). While it should work, it's slow and that's why I listed it here at the end

Comment: Is it a good practice to make registerUser method as synchronised?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you have to do it, it's ok.